# How to store a custom property in a Google Calendar event?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to store a custom property (a simple String) in a Google Calendar Event?

I tried this:

```
// inserting
Event event = new Event();
event.setSummary("test event");
event.set("customProperty", "custom value");
// event.get("customProperty") correctly returns "custom value" here
...
calendarService.events().insert("primary", event).execute();

// obtaining
Events events = calendarService.events().list("primary"). ... .execute();
List<Event> items = events.getItems();
for (Event event : items) {
    String result = (String) event.get("customProperty");
}
```

which creates the event with correct **summary**, but the **result** (my custom property) is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extended properties for this (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#extendedProperties) as they are a generic key-value store.

Depending on whether you want the properties to be available when looking at the guest copy of the event or not, you should choose shared or private extenedProperties.